# Looking for function identical to lodash's [_.set]()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for a function identical to lodash's [`_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs#set) except it should return a new object without modifying the original. Are there any implementations of this?

Right now I'm deep-cloning and then setting:

```
let data = _.cloneDeep(this.state.data);
_.set(data, name, value);
this.setState({data})
```

But I don't think it's necessary to do a full deep clone, we'd just need to do a shallow clone of the object at the deepest level, no?

e.g.

```
let oldData = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 }, 'd': {'e': 4} }] };
let newDate = withValue(oldData, 'a[0].b.c', 5);
```

The proposed `withValue` function would perform a shallow clone of `a`, `a[0]` and `a[0].b` and then modify the new `a[0].b.c` to 5. We would not need to make a copy of `a[0].d`.

Comment: No, that's not sufficient. This would not guarantee a mutation of the other object does not change the new one. So you either must deep-clone the plain JS object, or use something that wraps data structures for you (like immutablejs).

Comment: As of react - "unsetting" will not help, since react merges the passed object with the existing one.

Comment: @zerkms What if I know the old one (`this.state.data`) will never be mutated so I don't have to worry about it altering the new one?

Comment: `{...data, [name]: value}` <--- then that

Comment: @zerkms React does a shallow merge when calling `setState` doesn't it? I've put all this data in `this.state.data` so unsetting something *under* `this.state.data` should unset it forreal, no?

Comment: Nope. If some property is already in state - it will stay there forewer (unless you're using `replaceState`, which is not recommended to use by fb)

Comment: Problem with that is that I'm using dotted notation. Don't think `[squarebrackets]` supports `['a.b.c']`

Comment: Okay, I'll get rid of the `_.unset` then, was just hoping to save some memory, but it's not a big deal if it's `undefined`.

Comment: "was just hoping to save some memory" --- it's usually the opposite: if you remove a property from an object - it causes more memory allocations and CPU instructions to be emitted.

Comment: Good to know. I've just found [React's update helpers](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) but it doesn't appear to support dotted notation. Surely I'm not the only one to encounter this?

Comment: I'm using immutablejs, so no problem here ;-)

Comment: @mpen [Object.spread](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) is in stage 2, so you'll need to transpile if you want to use it.

Answer (score 6):

This is going to be a multi-part answer.

**Immutable set:**

As you're using lodash, you can use the [FP version of lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) and use `.set` (or [`.setWith`](https://lodash.com/docs#setWith) to be able to supply an object path) which will do an immutable update.

Or, as this looks like a React codebase you can use the [`$set` helper of React](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

Or you can just use the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const newObj = {...oldObj, prop: newValue }
```

Or Object.assign:

```
const newObj = Object.assign({}, oldObj, { prop: newValue });
```

**Performance:**

As you're mentioning performance (and not just deeply cloning an object) you might want to look in to an immutable framework. The more developed codebases increase performance by different measures. E.g. here's what [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) says:

> These data structures are highly efficient on modern JavaScript VMs by using structural sharing via hash maps tries and vector tries

...and [Mori](http://swannodette.github.io/mori/) says:

> Efficient immutable data structures - no cloning required [...] Modern JavaScript engines like V8, JavaScriptCore, and SpiderMonkey deliver the performance needed to implement persistent data structures well.

Comment: `$set`, spread, and `Object.assign` don't support dotted notation. FP version might work. Will React accept a `Immutable.Map` to `this.setState`? That's what you're suggesting I use right?

Comment: Personally I strongly recommend Immutable.js. Look at the `setIn` method to set deeply in an object. You can very much set the state to an Immutable.Map. I'd say that that's the most common use of Immutable ;)

Answer (score 5):

[lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) as [Emil suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36972465/65387) should work.

Example:

```
const setIn = require('lodash/fp/set');
this.setState({data: setIn(name, value, this.state.data)});
```

N.B. the argument order is different than regular lodash.