# Can this solution to merge two objects dynamically be simpler?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

If I have this `root` object:

```js
const root = {
    list: {
        first: false,
        second: false,
        third: false,
        forth: false
    }
};
```

and want to make a new object with the same structure but change a single variable. I can do it in the following way:

```js
const result = {
    ...root,
    list: {
        ...root.list,
        first: true
    }
}
```

So the result will be:

```json
{
  "list": {
    "first": true,
    "second": false,
    "third": false,
    "forth": false
  }
}
```

Everything works, but I need to do the same but in a **dynamic manner**. Let's say I pass the `root` object, the full path to property which needs to be updated `"list.first"` **as a string** and a value. I've found a solution:

```js
const merge = require('lodash').merge;

const root = {
    list: {
        first: false,
        second: false,
        third: false,
        forth: false
    }
};

function createObjectByPathAndValue(path, value) {
    const keys = (path || '').split('.') || [];

    function createObjectByPathAndValue(root, keys, value) {
        if (keys.length === 1) {
            root[keys[0]] = value;
        } else {
            const key = keys.splice(0, 1);
            root[key] = createObjectByPathAndValue({}, keys, value);
        }
        return root;
    }

    const result = createObjectByPathAndValue({}, keys, value);
    return result;
}

const changes = createObjectByPathAndValue('list.first', true);

const result = merge({}, root, changes);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null,2 ));
```

But let's agree that it's cumbersome, and too much code. I think that I don't use all possibilities of modern javascript and it can be done simpler. Am I right?

P.S. A new object must be created, i.e. mutating an existing object isn't permitted (I need it to update React's state)

Comment: What is your actual question? Merging two objects or creating an object? The merge part is two lines. Or is your actual question how to deep clone an object and change one value?

Comment: Actually, I need to create a new object with the modified property specified by the path to property `path.to.property` and value.

Comment: The title is misleading. This is not merging two objects. This is setting a (deep) property to a value. Lodash `set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deep clone your object and change the value:

```
const {cloneDeep, toPath, set} = require('lodash');

const root = {
    list: {
        first: false,
        second: false,
        third: false,
        forth: false
    }
};

const result = cloneDeep(root);
set(result, toPath('list.first'), true);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Here is an example (jsfiddle doesn't support `require`):

```js
const root = {
    list: {
        first: false,
        second: false,
        third: false,
        forth: false
    }
};

const result = _.cloneDeep(root);
_.set(result, _.toPath('list.first'), true);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, now say me how do you come from `"result.list.first"` to `result.list.first`, pay attention that first is a string, while second is an object.

Comment: I updated my answer because it might be not clear, I've given `"path.to.property"` by string, which I need to transform into the actual object.

Comment: Yes, I see. I upvoted it because it works but I will wait with accepting it meanwhile, wanna see other answers, maybe it can be done shorter. Thank you!

Comment: @Anatoly Lodash has a `set` function

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't know it. Also, I will look at at implementation of `set`, guess it's best possible.

Comment: Btw, lodash has fp version of `set` which creates a new object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36972679/947111

Answer (score 0):

I ended by using `set` function from `lodash/fn/set` package as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36972679/947111)

```js
const setFp = require('lodash/fp/set');

const root = {
    list: {
        first: false,
        second: false,
        third: false,
        forth: false
    }
};

const newRoot = setFp(`list.first`, true, root); //a new object will be created
```

Read more about [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) package.